# Elixir understanding GenServer

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, gen-server

I am new to Elixir and was reading through a book and doing some examples. Here is the piece of code that makes me ask question here:

```
defmodule Sequence.Server do
    use GenServer
    def init(initial_number)do 
        {:ok,initial_number}
    end

    def handle_call(:next_number, _from, current_number)do
        {:reply, current_number,current_number+1}    
    end 
end
```

As I know the **init** function is called when the server is being initialized and we are defining some parameter - which will be the initial state of the server. The thing that makes me confused is that how **current_number** and the **initial_number** are related to each other, I mean nowhere in the code we are saying something like that

> current_number = initial_number

Because when I call `GenServer.call(some_process_id, :next_number)` it starts from 100 for example if the parameter to **start_link** was 100. How does Elixir understands that it must start from 100 when we dont have any mapping between the initial state and the `current_number` parameters

Comment: i hope it helps you http://codefather.org/erlang-generic-behaviors/

Comment: I would like to suggest the great book of LYSE, specifically chapters https://learnyousomeerlang.com/more-on-multiprocessing and https://learnyousomeerlang.com/what-is-otp and https://learnyousomeerlang.com/clients-and-servers in order to understand how a gen_server (and other gen_* abstractions) are written. Reading whole book is highly recommended, and it's fun too :)

Comment: Thank you all :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of an `init/1` is to *setup up internal state of a `GenServer`*. The only way to amend this `GenServer`'s internal state, is via `call`-ing, `cast`-ing, or sending regular messages (then, being handled by `handle_info/2` callback).

Those functions (respectively, `handle_call/3` and `handle_cast/2`) will be invoked with the `GenServer`'s internal state passed in as the last argument of a function's argument.

Consider the scenario:

1. You're initialising the `GenServer` with number `100`.
2. You send a message (a `call` to be more specific) to this `GenServer` - `:next_number`.
3. This invokes your `handle_call(:next_number, _from, current_number)` callback function, where `current_number` has the initial value of `100`.
4. As a return value from this function, you specified the tuple: `{:reply, current_number,current_number+1}`, which you should understand like: `reply` (first element of a tuple) indicates it will reply to the caller; the second element of the tuple will be the value returned to caller (in this case, it will be number `100`); and the last element of the tuple will be the **new state of a `GenServer`** - `current_number+1`, so `101`.
5. When you send another `:next_number` `call` to this `GenServer`, it will follow the previous steps, except, the internal state will now be `101`, and after returning from the function, the new state will be `102`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

The result of `init` is `{:ok, initial_state}`, where the state value is **held by `GenServer`**.

The signature of `handle_call` is actually `handle_call(request, from, current_state)`, and it returns `{:reply, result, new_state}`.

This means that when you do `GenServer.call(pid, :next_number)`, that results in a call to `handle_call(:next_number, _from, state)`, where the state -- passed as `current_number` -- starts as `initial_number` and the result of `handle_call` saves a new state with value `current_number`.

The next time you call `GenServer.call(pid, :next_number)`, it's called with the new state, and you return the new-new state, and so on...